# Java image transformation

Tags: java, image, transform

I need to create 3d depth effect for my image. Number 1 is what I have and number 2 is shape where I want to transform number 1. So is there any method for that in Java standard graphics libraries or some other open source libraries?

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366099/skew-or-distort-image-object-in-java/52187377#52187377) is of help. It uses no external libraries, only JavaFX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can not be done using the `AffineTransform` class. See Wikipedia article on affine transformation:

> *In general, an affine transformation is composed of linear transformations (rotation, scaling or shear) and a translation (or "shift").*

What you need is some form of perspective transform. From http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/PerspectiveTransform.html

> *A perspective transformation is capable of mapping an arbitrary quadrilateral into another arbitrary quadrilateral, while preserving the straightness of lines. **Unlike an affine transformation, the parallelism of lines in the source is not necessarily preserved in the output.***

From http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/515829.html

> The Java Advanced Imaging API allows you to easily perform perspective transform.
>
> As in Java2D and Java3D, these routines are optimised, they are not
>   run in the usual java interpreted manner - so they are very fast as
>   well.
>
> The JAI is downloadable from
>
> http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/downloads/download-1_1_2.html
>
> You can find info on how to run perspective transform in:
>
> http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/

Comment: Thanx for help, but I didn't find any example how to use JAI perspective transformation, and it's JavaDocs are pretty uninformative...

Comment: Someone helped me out with the math portion of this question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217370/how-can-i-project-an-arbitrary-plane-identified-by-4-points-unto-a-2d-plane

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a lot of fast drawing in 3D then I'd suggest looking into a 3D rendering solution such as OpenGL / JOGL.

If it is just a quick one-off transformation then you can simulate this pretty easily by

- Looping over all the lines in 2.
- Scaling the corresponding line in 1. and drawing it over the line in 2, stretching it to the right proportion (you'll need some basic maths to work this out)